# accessing vector inside a vector in Java

Tags: java, swing, jtable, defaulttablemodel

I have populated a jTable from a database, now i want to add more functiaonality, I want to delete a row, i have my data structure like this:

```
public Vector getUser()throws Exception {

Vector<Vector<String>> userVector = new Vector<Vector<String>>();

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
conn = DriverManager.getConnection(DB_URL,USER,PASS);
PreparedStatement pre = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM korisnici");
 rs = pre.executeQuery();


while (rs.next()) {
    Vector<String> user = new Vector<String>();
    user.add(rs.getString(1)); 
    user.add(rs.getString(2)); 
    user.add(rs.getString(3)); 
    user.add(rs.getString(4)); 
    userVector.add(user);
}

if (conn!=null)
    conn.close();

return userVector;
}
```

next I created a jTable with model like this

```
jTable1.setModel(new javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel(
        data,header
    ));
```

so now i want to delete row using

```
jTable1.remove(int);
```

My db has 7 rows and when i put int=1 i get outOfBoundsException:1

I'm acesing it wrong, right? How do i remove a row, properly?

Comment: You add `data` to the `DefaultTableModel`, is vector somehow linked to the `userVector`? I feel like a lot of necessary code is missing. And... [How to remove a row from JTable?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1117888/how-to-remove-a-row-from-jtable)

Comment: `jTable1.remove(int);` JTable does not have a remove() method. The method you are invoking is the `Container.remove(...)`, which is usually used to remove components from a panel, not a table, since a table doesn't contain any child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove a row from the table, you want

```
((DefaultTableModel)jTable.getModel()).removeRow(rowToRemove);
```

The `JTable` itself is really just some display logic: it's the table model underneath that controls the data, and it's that that you need to interact with. The table itself will then render whatever's present in the table model.

Since you're creating the `DefaultTableModel` yourself, the easier overall way of achieving this would be to set the model via

```
DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(data,header);
jTable1.setModel(model);
```

and then later on

```
model.removeRow(rowToRemove);
```

That saves you querying the table to find the table model every time.

Answer (score 2):

Use `DefaultTableModel` for deleting a row based on row number.

```
((DefaultTableModel) table.getModel()).removeRow(row)
```

For detail explanation please have a look at [How to Use Tables](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html)

[Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25338260/rows-not-deleted-from-jtable/25338393#25338393) and [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18615089/java-add-remove-row-to-jtable)

Answer (score 0):

Now i have it working to remove record from JTable, but now I want to remove it from db also, I have it working when i enter a string manually but i want to remove it from db by clicking on it. Here is what i have

```
PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement("DELETE FROM user WHERE JMBG = ? ");
         ps.setString(1, value2);
         ps.executeUpdate();
```

where value2 is a String.
How I set value2 to get value from a mouse click?

I got it it works as next:

```
value2=(String) ((DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel()).getValueAt(row, 2);
```

where row is

```
int row = jTable1.getSelectedRow();
```

It was very messy at start, deleteing random stuff, but now it works as intended